# how libJinbgle server handle voicemail?

Tags: webrtc, libjingle, voicemail

I'm trying to understand how this call scenario is implemented in WebRTC / libJingle:

Caller A want to call callee B but B is not online so server redirects A to a voice mail.

After A send connection requests to server, and XMPP server don't have B in the presence list, what happens? How the server redirects the caller to a voicemail instead of continue with the regular call flow?  What messages are returned to A? ...

Comment: This is not something that webrtc is concerned with. It rather depends on the specific technologies used.

Comment: Its related to libJingle more than to the webRTC